# Maximizing Output from ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

Given a system of differential equations that are dependent on two parameters, such as the system below (the equation below is not that important, I am interested in a general procedure given a parametric diff equation)

$\alpha \ddot{x}(t) + y(t)\dot{x}(t) = 1  $ and $\beta \ddot{y}(t) + x(t)\dot{y}(t)=2 $

How can one use ParametricNDSolve and NMaximize for the above system, using $\alpha $ and $\beta$ as parameters, in order to find the values of $\alpha, \beta$ and the time $t$ such that the quantity $(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2)*Sin(ArcTan(\dot{y}/\dot{x}))$ is maximum?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is badly formulated:  ParametricNDSolve needs initial/boundary conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Let me give a little example.

Since i am working with MMa version 8.0, where `ParametricNDSolve` is not jet implemented, here a little workaround. Please adapt it to `ParametricNDSolve`.
I add intial conditions and look for minimum, not maximum, here.

```
eqs = {alpha* Derivative[2, 0, 0][x][t, alpha, beta] + 
y[t, alpha, beta]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][t, alpha, beta] == 1, 
beta* Derivative[2, 0, 0][y][t, alpha, beta] + 
x[t, alpha, beta]*Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][t, alpha, beta] == 2, 
x[0, alpha, beta] == 1, Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][0, alpha, beta] == 2,
y[0, alpha, beta] == 2, 
Derivative[1, 0, 0][y][0, alpha, beta] == 1}

ndsol = NDSolve[eqs, {x, y}, {t, 0, 10}, {alpha, 1, 2}, {beta, 2, 3}]

Plot[x[t, 1, 3] /. First@ndsol, {t, 0, 10}]

Manipulate[
  Plot[(Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][t, alpha, beta]^2 + 
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][y][t, alpha, beta]^2)*
Sin[ArcTan[
  Derivative[1, 0, 0][y][t, alpha, beta]/
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][t, alpha, beta]]] /. First@ndsol, {t, 0,
10}, PlotRange -> {0, 2}], {alpha, 1, 2}, {beta, 2, 3}]

Minimize[Evaluate[{(Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][t, alpha, beta]^2 + 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][y][t, alpha, beta]^2)*
 Sin[ArcTan[
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][y][t, alpha, beta]/
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][x][t, alpha, beta]]] /. First@ndsol, 
 0 < t < 10 && 1 < alpha < 2 && 2 < beta < 3}], {t, alpha, beta}]

(*   {0.955927, {t -> 1.32343, alpha -> 2., beta -> 2.}}   *)
```